# MySQL connection using DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, mysql

I've tried to connect to mysql using DefaultHttpClient, but so far no success. **Error connection refused.**

I can telnet MySQL using telnet 127.0.0.1 3306

enter code here

I'am using this example from apache website

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope("localhost", 3306), 
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://localhost:3306");

        System.out.println("executing request" + httpget.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

enter code here

am I missing some concept for instance do I need a webserver or server side language like PHP?

I want to login, perform select, etc using http is that possible?

Regards,

Comment: What language is this? (hint: add the tag, more users will answer). Also, unless the naming convention is wrong, it would be a weird setup that MySQL talks HTTP,  it really doesn't out of the box. Enfin: usual MySQL suspect is: try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Answer (score 4):

DefaultHttpClient is for making connections to http servers, not to MySQL servers. Check out JDBC: http://java.sun.com/products/jdbc/overview.html

Comment: but jdbc is not to use only over networking? So should I use jdbc over http?